# php exec() not running python script

Tags: php, python

i run the python script bellow in the command line and it works fine, but when i execute it in a php file it returns an empty array.

**python**

```
import sys

id_input=sys.argv[1] 

print id_input
```

**php**

```
<?php


$out="";
exec("python teste.py a  ",$out);
print_r($out);

?>
```

output of php: array()

output in command line: a

Both files are in the same directory and i am using XAMPP in Vista OS to run them.

Comment: Try using the full path to python, not sure where that would be in Vista

Comment: it worked ! Should i always write the full path in php files?

Comment: For most things, yes. PHP isn't aware of the environment variables, it's the same in Linux too

Comment: Didn't know. I think this will be an important post for beginners in php-python.

Comment: Added as an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments... the problem was that you need to specify the full path to the python binary, because PHP is not aware of the environmental variables such as PATH